# How would you go about implementing a function that gives us months between two dates?

Tags: date

So I have a great debate going on at work as to how a months_between function should be implemented. There are so many ways to implement this.

- We could have a system where we take the difference of the days and divide by some integer 31 or 30.
- We could have a system that returns the days between the two dates and divide by some integer 31 or 30
- We could have a system where we get the percentage of the first month remaining + percent of last month included + number of months between
- We could just give up on a decimal notation and return a rounded/floored/ceiled int
- Inverse of a function that simply adds 1 to the month

etc etc

Comment: I wouldn't code this myself. Find a good library that gets it right.

Comment: There are many other considerations (like how many months are between Dec 31, 2013 and Jan 1, 2014, handling leap years, etc.). There are libraries in almost every language that take all of this into consideration, so why would you want to waste time reinventing the wheel when you could use it instead actually doing something productive? (Your question is also too broad in scope for this site; you're asking for a discussion and brainstorming session, and this site is for *specific problems you're now facing*.)

Comment: There can't be any non-opinion-based answer to this question without more information. Why "months between"? Why not "x months y days"? This is strongly dependant on "the problem". What kind of information do you want to be transported by this value?

Comment: I agree. I think there is no real answer because this question is not objective. But would finding a "good library" really solve this problem...

Comment: If you are aware that your question is not objective, you must also be aware that it is off-topic according to the site guidelines in the [help/on-topic], right?

Comment: Well I'm not sure about that. Maybe there's a standard out there that solves this question for me, I can't tell until I ask.

Comment: @wonton As has been stated by Ken White, there are libraries in most languages for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/214134

```
public int MonthsBetweenDates(int start_month, int start_year, int end_month, int end_year)
{
    int months = ((end_year - start_year) * 12);
    months += (end_month - start_month) * (months < 0 ? -1 : 1);            
    return months;
}
```

This gives an integer value which I think makes sense when you're considering months.